# How to repeat same With statements on multiple objects?

Tags: excel, with-statement

I am setting up a dynamic report and would like to filter multiple pivot tables at the same time as I change one cell value. I have no experience in VBA and cannot find anyone within my company that can help.

Since the pivot tables are separate objects, I define them all as different dimensions and point these dimensions to the different pivot tables but the cell that is meant to dictate the pivot table filter stays the same. Below are modified from my google search. Original codes worked fine updating 1 pivot table. After my ignorant attempt at modifying the codes, I ended up with application-defined or object-defined error.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("D1:D2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Field As PivotField
Dim NewCat As String

Dim pt1 As PivotTable
Dim Field1 As PivotField
Dim NewCat1 As String

Set pt = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Code")
NewCat = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value

Set pt1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("Pivotable2")
Set Field1 = pt1.PivotFields("Code")
NewCat1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D1").Value

With pt
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.CurrentPage = NewCat
pt.RefreshTable

End With

With pt1
Field1.ClearAllFilters
Field1.CurrentPage = NewCat1
pt1.RefreshTable

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a search on here for loops.

Comment: The With command simply instructs the compiler to insert the object that follows the With statement in front of any item that begins with a full stop. Since you don't start anythng with a full stop in your With/End With blocks it does nothing.